# Intersection of two lists in clojure

Tags: clojure

context: this is somewhat related to project euler problem 5, which is:

*What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?*

I apply prime number decomposition to the range of numbers from 1 to 20, and the product of all that should be the smallest number.

```
(absorb '(2 2 2) '(2 3 4)) -> '(2 2 2 3 4) ;; does not have to be sorted

(defn absorb [seq1 seq2]
  (loop [s1 (sort seq1)
         s2 (sort seq2)
         acc '()]
    (let [s1-curr (first s1)
          s2-curr (first s2)]
      (cond (and (empty? s1) (empty? s2)) acc
            (empty? s1) (into s2 acc)
            (empty? s2) (into s1 acc)
            (= s1-curr s2-curr) (recur (rest s1) (rest s2) (cons s1-curr acc))
            :else (recur (rest s1) s2 (cons s1-curr acc))))))
```

Is there a way to write this in more idiomatic Clojure, or a more optimized/clea er version?

Comment: By the way, there's a faster and simpler way to solve Euler 5, which asks you for the [least common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) (lcm) of numbers up to `20`: Calculate the lcm of two numbers as the product divided by the greatest common divisor (gcd). The gcd and hence the lcm are quick to calculate. And lcm distributes just as addition and multiplication do.

Answer (score 1):

My assumption is that you want to keep the maximal count so that if `2` occurs 4 times in one list and `2` occurs 3 times in another, `2` will appear 4 times in the result.

In this case, I would write the following:

```
(defn elem-counts [coll]
   (reduce (fn [acc val] (assoc acc val (inc (acc val 0)))) {} coll))
```

With this, I can get the map from values in the collection to the number of times it occurs.

Now, for a way to reverse this process (from a map of counts to the list that would create the map):

```
(defn seq-from-counts [count-map]
   (flatten (for [[k v] count-map] (repeat v k))))
```

Finally, your intersect becomes:

```
(defn absorb [list1 list2]
   (seq-from-counts (merge-with max 
                                (elem-counts list1) 
                                (elem-counts list2))))
```

Comment: See [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/136088/43360).

Answer (score 0):

This is an extended comment on @HemanGandhi's answer.

- The `elem-counts` function is just the standard `frequencies`
  function.
- There is no need to regenerate the list: `seq-from-counts` is
  redundant. Just work with the frequency maps, which are
  functioning as [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset)s.

Comment: Thanks! (I was looking for `frequencies`, but couldn't find it.) Also, I didn't use multisets since the question seemed based on lists.